# Problem with displaying images on Facebook from my wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

When posting link to my wordpress [geekgirlscarrots.pl](http://geekgirlscarrots.pl) on Facebook, thumbnail images don't display at all.

I've put at header the following code:

```
<meta name="title" content="Geek Girls Carrots" />
<meta name="description" content="Visit our site! Come to our meetings!" />
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://geekgirlscarrots.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/1GGC_for_web_logo.jpg"/>
```

but it doesn't work. If anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) specifically this one

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://geekgirlscarrots.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/1GGC_for_web_logo.jpg"/>
```

The linked image image needs to be 50 x 50 px.

It should be accompanied with these other og: tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my.url.html"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Webmaster Blog"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="blog"/>
```

Make sure you [set type correctly](http://set%20type%20correctly) there is a [useful summary on effective use here](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/03/29/like-button-open-graph-tags/).

**These shouldn't replace your normal meta tags, but exist in addition to them.**